# Нужно сделать зависимые таблицы

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

[image: Дизайн]

Мне нужно чтоб при выборе техники были марки этой техники. Очень прошу помочь с таблицами, я не знаю как в одну таблицу заносить разные данные. Буду рад любой помощи(от идеи до реализации).

Comment: Уважаемые форумчане! Если вы минусуете мой пост, то будьте добры, объясните в чем причина! Я в разработке подобных программ новичок и многого не понимаю. Гуглом пользоваться умею но для данному вопросу я ничего найти не смог. Благодарю за внимание!

Comment: Я думаю, что вас заминусовали, поскольку налицо нежелание разбираться. Вам надо прочитать документацию по UITableView, и я думаю после этого вопрос пропадет.

Comment: Спасибо за чесность.

Comment: я предполагаю, что у вас уже есть таблица. То есть вам надо, когда пользователь выбирает ячейку, записать в переменную, что теперь вы хотите показывать марки, и запустить `[tableView reloadData];`. а в cellForRowAtIndexPath проверить значение переменной указанной выше и заполнить таблицу новыми данными.

Comment: Да. Это то что мне нужно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я предполагаю, что у вас уже есть таблица. То есть вам надо, когда пользователь выбирает ячейку, записать в переменную, что теперь вы хотите показывать марки, и запустить `[tableView reloadData];`. а в `cellForRowAtIndexPath` проверить значение переменной указанной выше и заполнить таблицу новыми данными.